# Are there constants for CSS properties and values in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is some code that I wrote:

```
var shouldDisplayError = PageHasError();
lblError.Attributes["display"] = shouldDisplayError ? "block" : "none";
```

I would like to use constants instead of string literals to avoid the possibility of typos and because I just find using constants to be cleaner for some unexplainable reason.

I could not find a constants library myself (searching for things like "C# CSS properties constants" without quotes). Writing my own constants class seems like overkill for my use case. Does ASP.NET have a collection of constants for CSS properties and values?

Comment: No there isn't you could define your own enums though and use those.  However, this enum would be growing in size..there are so many different literal strings you'd get confused.

Comment: @JonH "No there isn't." sounds like a valid answer to me. Want to post it as an answer? As I said in the question, writing my own constants class seems like overkill for my use case. The amount of time it would take to do that outweighs the amount of time it would save me in the long run (which is not much time at all given the size of the project).

Comment: sure, I'd suggest just being extra careful as to avoid misspellings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't you could define your own `enum` though and use those. However, this `enum` would be growing in size..there are so many different literal strings you'd get confused and you'd have to maintain it.

Case in point, it's just not worth it.